# awk: Remove duplicates and create a new csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have following CSV file:

```
1393036,293296,68,59,Mithridates,ny,io
10155431,14595886,1807,135860,Riemogerz,ny,id
10767895,5749707,2402,1716,Nickispeaki,ny,uk
1536088,6390442,1301,109160,Ds02006,ny,ru
353,291765,434,434,Lar,ny,en,en-N
19332,7401441,296,352647,WikiDreamer,ny,fr
7142,7221255,298,78928,WikiDreamer Bot,ny,fi
417258,1507888,409,7709,Dmitri Lytov,ny,ru
7198454,15101351,5604,853415,Ffffnm,cdo,zh
1536088,6390442,1301,109160,Ds02006,ny,ru
353,291765,434,434,Lar,ny,en
```

I want to remove the duplicates based on the value of the first column. If there are more than one record of the same value I want to only keep one in the new file:

I started with following which actually finds the duplicates but I want to create a new file instead of just printing:

```
sort input.csv | awk 'NR == 1 {p=$1; next} p == $1 { print $1 " is duplicated"} {p=$1}' FS=","
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nut 100% sure what you like, but this will only get the last input if there are equals:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=$0} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file > newfile
cat newfile
417258,1507888,409,7709,Dmitri Lytov,ny,ru
7198454,15101351,5604,853415,Ffffnm,cdo,zh
7142,7221255,298,78928,WikiDreamer Bot,ny,fi
10767895,5749707,2402,1716,Nickispeaki,ny,uk
1536088,6390442,1301,109160,Ds02006,ny,ru
1393036,293296,68,59,Mithridates,ny,io
353,291765,434,434,Lar,ny,en
10155431,14595886,1807,135860,Riemogerz,ny,id
19332,7401441,296,352647,WikiDreamer,ny,fr
```

---

If its not important what record to keep, as long as field  `1` is unique.
This will show the first hit if there are several equal:

```
awk -F, '!a[$1]++' file > newfile
cat newfile
1393036,293296,68,59,Mithridates,ny,io
10155431,14595886,1807,135860,Riemogerz,ny,id
10767895,5749707,2402,1716,Nickispeaki,ny,uk
1536088,6390442,1301,109160,Ds02006,ny,ru
353,291765,434,434,Lar,ny,en,en-N
19332,7401441,296,352647,WikiDreamer,ny,fr
7142,7221255,298,78928,WikiDreamer Bot,ny,fi
417258,1507888,409,7709,Dmitri Lytov,ny,ru
7198454,15101351,5604,853415,Ffffnm,cdo,zh
```

---

To get the duplicated into a new file:

```
awk -F, '++a[$1]==2 {print $1}' file > newfile
cat newfile
1536088
353
```

Comment: I had a header on the csv file but after I create the new file based on you first block of the code I lost the header. How do i keep the header?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis Add this in start of code: `NR==1 {print;next}` eks: `awk -F, 'NR==1 {print;next} !a[$1]++' file > newfile`  This way line `1` always goes to `newfile`

Comment: This will use quite a bit of memory on a large file as well as having to traverse the file as well as the array. If you print the first time you see a line, you don't have to save it.

Answer (score 3):

This will show only the first entry for a given first column value:

```
awk -F, '!(seen[$1]++)' file > newfile
```